# How to assign thymleaf variable to ng-model

Tags: angularjs, thymeleaf

How can I assign a thymeleaf variable value to `ng-model`. I want to do something like this:
`<input type="text" th:ng-init="myInput=${serverData.myInput}" ng-model="myInput" />`

Answer (score 1):

You may set value from thymeleaf to grobal js variable:

```
<script>
    var dataFromThymeleaf = {
        myInput: "[[${serverData.myInput}]]"
    }
</script>
```

And then copy this value to scope from angular controller:

`$scope.myInput = dataFromThymeleaf.myInput`